# Error when trying to call cloud function to set Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to add functionality where the app calls a cloud function using HTTPS, and the cloud function stores data in Firestore. I worked through the Google tutorials and other Stackoverflow answers, but did not see an example with similar syntax. Please see below the line that is causing the error "unexpected token admin". Thank you so much!

```
exports.addData = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // ...
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('data-store').add({index: dataToAdd});
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. "async" should be added to the function call. When I modified the code to the below, the error goes away:

```
exports.addData = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    // ...
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('data-store').add({index: dataToAdd});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The code presumes you've imported (or required) `admin` around the top of the file...

```
// Pre ES2015
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

// modern
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

And these presume you've npm installed firebase-admin. More complete instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

Comment: I had included these in my run but still achieved this result; I previously was able to run the code from the Google tutorial, but received the admin error when trying to run my above code.